# simple phar file causes redirect loop in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, phar

I'm creating a web based phar installer for a content management system.  The problem is on nginx servers, even the simplest of phar files causes a redirect in nginx.  Everything works fine in apache.

My experience with nginx is minimal, so I can't figure this out. Looking for all, and any help I can get.  Thanks in advance.

**Sources:**

Here is the build script for the .phar *(I rename the .phar to .php so that no funky .htaccess rules are required)*

```
<?php
// create with alias "project.phar"
$phar = new Phar('test.phar', 0, 'test.phar');
$phar->buildFromDirectory('./files');
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub('cli.php', 'index.php'));
@rename('test.phar','test.php');
?>
```

Here is the simple index.php file

```
<?php
echo "This does not work in nginx\n";
?>
```

Here is the nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.php;

    include /etc/nginx/include/php;

    location /test2 {
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

and the /etc/nginx/include/php file

```
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/nginx/php-fastcgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

and the fastcgi_params file

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

**edit**

This problem is related to fastcgi mode as I've reproduced it in apache using the same handler.
the default stub causes a redirect loop, requiring me to use a fixed stub.  I will post another question

Comment: phar files are not processed by the fastcgi until you add it to the `location` pattern `[^/]\.(php|phar)(/|$)` and also in `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.(?:php|phar))(/.*)$;` but i'm not sure that `$fastcgi_path_info` will be filled in this case.

Comment: The file is renamed to test.php to get around that problem.  I get a redirect loop though.

Comment: You renaming is causing the loop. I think you should try creating the file locally and then issuing ajax download request with correct MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen such a redirection loop myself and reported the bug - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67587

The bug has been fixed in PHP now; PHP 5.6.0, 5.5.15 and 5.4.31.